# Can someone help me with this conditional probability problem?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Here is the problem.

> Box A contains 5 dark chocolates and 10 milk chocolates. Box B
>   contains 12 dark chocolates and 12 milk chocolates. Craig picks a box
>   at random and then takes out one chocolate at random.

```
 What is the probability that he gets a dark chocolate?
```

**My answer was

5/15+12/24 = 5/6**

**Then I multiplied it by 1/2
to get**

> =5/12

I don't think this is correct but, **Please don't give me the answer!!.**

Comment: The problem is incompletely specified with just the words "at random". For example, does he pick each box with **equal** probability (that makes a difference to the answer)? And then within each box, each chocolate with equal probability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M$ be the event of picking milk chocolate, $D$ the event of picking dark chocolate, $A$ the event of picking box $A$ and $B$ the event of picking box $B$. Assuming the boxes are picked with equal probability, we have that $P(A)= 1/2$, $P(B)= 1/2$, $P(D|A)= 5/15$ and $P(D|B)= 12/24$. By the total law of probability we then have that $$P(D)= P(D|A)P(A)+P(D|B)P(B)=\frac {5}{15} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{12}{24}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{12}$$ so you're correct.

Comment: Thanks so much Alex, you've made my day.

Comment: @BlakeJacobs Noting Mathemagical's comment, if the boxes are picked with non-equal probabilities, i,e. box $A$ is picked with probability $p$ and box $B$ is picked with probability $1-p$ then you simply replace $P(A)=p$ and $P(B)=1-p$.

Comment: Cheers everybody, this has helped a lot.

Comment: @BlakeJacobs If you are satisfied with the answer you can click the check-mark next to it to mark it as the accepted answer.